# How to persist Clojure sets/keywords in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, clojure

Before I go ahead and write database wrappers to read and write Clojure sets and keywords to mongo, I was wondering if there are any solutions out there people are already using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a Clojure driver for Mongodb?  It might be worth taking a look at http://clojuremongodb.info/.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more specific; that is indeed what I was looking for. Monger seems to have it exactly.